# How to destruct Terminal object provided by hterm?

Tags: javascript

I'm using libapps/hterm. I had read [the document](https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/HEAD/hterm/doc/hack.md#JS-Life-cycle) about how to construct a `hterm.Terminal` and use it.

But I didn't find anything helpful about how can I destroy the Terminal.

How can I do that?

Here, destroy means remove the DOM element, remove event listeners, and make the Terminal object may be GCed.

Comment: Maybe I need some other tags, but I cannot find them...

Comment: No answer and no comment, maybe I will try `<iframe>` now...

Answer (score 0):

Hterm is already using an iframe for the terminal. When you call hterms decorate method you are telling hterm that your div is the container to be used for the terminal You can hide the div that was used to decorate the terminal by setting it to display:none. This will not free up the object to free the object set the variable that is referring the hterm.terminal object and any other variables In your code that reference hterm to null. Once there are no references to the object, the garbage collector will free its memory.